# Resistor as inrush current limiter - power drain?

Tags: current

I have a 3V DC circuit that consumes 5-15 mA.  I suspect that charging capacitors when turning the unit on is causing an inrush that is welding/sticking the reed switch.  All of the circuit current flows through the reed switch.

Would a resistor or capacitor in series or parallel with the reed switch slow the inrush to a manageable level (eg 100-500mA?)  Which solution would you suggest?  (Capacitor or resistor, series or parallel.)

I am not an EE, just an IT guy hobbyist developing a cool new product.  Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: Reed relay? Specification/datasheet for whatever it is?

Comment: What do you mean "what would the current drain of the resistor be"?

Comment: Updated the question for clarity.  The entire 5-15mA current of this circuit flows through a reed switch that is rated for 100-500mA.  The circuit is powered by 2x AAA batteries, and the reed switch is connected to the positive terminal of the battery pack to open/close the circuit.

The circuit contains a dozen small electrolytic capacitors, and I suspect that the inrush of charging all these capacitors is momentarily exceeding the  100-500mA rating of the reed switch, causing the reed to stick.

I'm looking to slow this inrush down to <100mA.

Comment: If you provide a datasheet for the reed relay, I can definitely answer your question.

Comment: Thank you sir!!!  Here is the data sheet: https://standexelectronics.com/viewer/pdfjs/web/viewer.php?file=https%3A%2F%2Fstandexelectronics.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F03%2FMK16_V02.pdf

Comment: Sometimes just an NTC resistor in series will do.  It starts with some resistance, but quickly lowers its resistance so it doesn't waste as much power.

Comment: There are dedicated soft-start current limiter (from the usual chip manufacturers). In fact many of load switch circuitry is available with inrush limiter. Are you sure it's a good idea to power the circuit with the reed instead of using the reed as a control signal? Of course depends on the application

Answer (score 0):

The initial current will limited only by the cap effective series resistance or I=V/ESR.

Common solutions are a constant current limiter which also drops the voltage initially.

The other solution is a metal oxide inrush current limiter, or ICL which are very low cost and come in various values avail. At large distis like Digikey/Mouser.

Answer (score 0):

Update!  The addition of a 3.3 ohm resistor in series with the reed switch solved my problem.  A 1 ohm and 10 ohm also worked, so I decided to split the difference with 3.3.  1 ohm seemed to be cutting it too close, and 10 ohm would have needlessly wasted battery power.

Thank you all for your assistance!  Now my hunt for an inrush meter that will measure tiny amounts of current continues.  All the inrush meters I have found are ma